# Iterate over array object with condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to get data from array of object with ES6 way.

I have array object.

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 'first',
    description: "some desc",
    url: firstUrl,
  },
  {
    title: 'second',
    description: "some desc",
    url: secondUrl,
  },
];
```

**I am trying to check if there is `title === 'second'` then return it's url else return `firstUrl`**

I know I can do it with for loop. But, I want it with ES6 way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried:

```
let text = data.map((val) => { val.title === 'second' ? val.url : val.url });
```

But, not working and I know it's not good way.

Comment: do you have always the default object at index zero?

Comment: `const filteredData = (title) => data.filter(i => i.title === title).map(i => i.url);`?

Comment: `map` is used to map the original values into other values, so it doesn't make sense to use it. Like @Boris Drekevist said, keep it simple

Comment: Will your `data` array always contain 2 elements or can it vary?

Comment: @k0pernikus It could be vary. Then there should be first one selected if not second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, you check if you have a second item in your array (condition `title === 'second'`) and then you either use it or you fallback to the first one. if first (or second) is `undefined` you would get an `Undefinded reference` erro in line (*)

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: 'first',
    description: "some desc",
    url: 'firstUrl',
  },
  {
    title: 'second',
    description: "some desc",
    url: 'secondUrl',
  },
];

// if your order is allways first and second (0 and 1) you can do this 
// const urlObject = data[1] || data[0]
const urlObject = data.find(item => item.title === 'second') || data.find(item => item.title === 'first')

// here you have your url
console.log(urlObject.url) // line (*)
```

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by more objects in array ?

Comment: Sorry by mistake. :)

Comment: This loops twice over `data`. If you are only interested if a "second" title exists, otherwise default to first entry, this is not necessary. If you want to default to the element with title `first`, this works though you could avoid the unnecessary loop.

Comment: @k0pernikus i am not sure about the data's structure so i added another loop, tho i pointed out that if you expect the same order in your data you should just use the index.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const secondItem = data.find(item => item.title === 'second')
const url = secondItem ? secondItem.url || firstUrl
```

just keep it simple like this

Comment: How you fetch firstUrl ? If I remove second object from array then it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object and assign the wanted key to the object. For other default titels take `default`.

For getting a result take the wanted key or default.

```js
const
    data = [{ title: 'first', description: "some desc", url: 'firstUrl' }, { title: 'second', description: "some desc", url: 'secondUrl' }],
    temp = data.reduce((r, { title, url }) => {
        r[title === 'second' ? title : 'default'] = url;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(temp.second || temp.default);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **reduce** instead of other method (like map) if *only one computed element* is needed.

Also if the default is the first element, then I would start from the end of the array serching the **second** and then, if it is not present, I would return the first.

So ***reduceRight*** seems to be the best option

```
const data = [
    // ...
];

let text = data.reduceRight((prev, {title, url}, i) => {
    if(prev) {
        return prev
    }
    if(title === 'second' || i === 0) {
        return url
    }
}, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to know if there is a "second" object and otherwise use the first element of the array, you can make use of `.find()`.

```
const secondItem = data.find(e => e.title === "second"); // secondItem will be undefined if not found
const result = secondItem ? secondItem.url : data[0].url;
```

You should also check for the edge case that data might be an empty array. The above code would throw an error when accessing the default case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check if `second` exists. If so, grab its URL, otherwise, fallback to `first`'s URL like so:

With both: you get the second URL

```js
const data = [{
    title: 'first',
    description: "some desc",
    url: "firstUrl"
  },
  {
    title: 'second',
    description: "some desc",
    url: "secondUrl"
  }
];

const targetURL = data[1] ? data[1].url : data[0].url;

console.log(targetURL);
```

With `first` only, you get `first'`s URL:

```js
const data = [{
  title: 'first',
  description: "some desc",
  url: "firstUrl"
}];

const targetURL = data[1] ? data[1].url : data[0].url;

console.log(targetURL);
```

Also note that you need to wrap your URL values in quotes otherwise they're called as variables which leads to errors.